# How to install another copy of the program via PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I would like to install another copy of Windows game via PlayOnLinux for testing and experimenting, under a new Wine prefix. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start PlayOnLinux and then click **Install** button here. It will create new Wine prefix for you. Follow the wizard.